# Having array of Indices and want to bring its rows from a dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a data frame which looks like:

```
In: df.head()

Out:
Index   Country       Gender   Age   
0        USA            M      30   
1        Australia      F      22   
2        China          F      66   
3        Spain          M      88
```

And I created an array (my_array) with numbers which corresponds to the row index of our DataFrame. The array looks like:

```
In:  my_array
Out: array([[3],
            [2],
            [3],
            [0]])
```

My question is i want to bring or return the rows by the selected indices in my array and in the same order.

If my array has these indices: 3, 2, 3, 0. So, i want to return the rows from these indices. And i dont want to do it manually.

The output should look like this:

```
Index   Country       Gender   Age   
3        Spain          M      88   
2        China          F      66   
3        Spain          M      88   
0        USA            M      30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `df.iloc[my_array]` should do it for you.

My example:

```
In [306]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[306]: 
   col1  col2 col3
0    75    84    A
1    84    68    B
2    75    84    C
3    75    84    A

In [307]: a = [3,2,3,0]

In [309]: df.iloc[a]                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[309]: 
   col1  col2 col3
3    75    84    A
2    75    84    C
3    75    84    A
0    75    84    A
```